# Trying to load a model that contains 2 lists of different objects in a modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my goal:

1. I have an 'EventViewModel' class that contains a List <_EventsLine> and a List <_SubEventsLine>.
2. I display the list of all the events of a member (according to the id of a member).
3. If the user clicks on the name of an event, a modal opens and must display the details of the event (in the upper part of the modal) and a table that lists all the sub-events to which the member is registered.

I managed to implement almost all of my goal but I miss all that the last step: display the list of sub-events in the modal.

I do have a partial view for the details of the event in the modal and I also have a second partial view for the table (sub-events) in the modal.

Currently the modal opens and displays the top part but not the table with the sub-events, I receive an error 500  on Chrome debugger.
I think this error has to be related to my view code but I can not figure how to solve it

Do you have an idea?

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new EventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    var xtoFind = new SubEventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var xresults = await client.FindAsync(xtoFind);

    EventViewModel oEventViewModel = new EventViewModel
    {
        _EventsLines = (from o in results select o).ToList(),
        _SubEventsLines = (from x in xresults select x).ToList()
    };

    return View(oEventViewModel);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEventsDetails(int id)
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new EventsLines { Zkp = id };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return View();
    }

    EventsLines oEventViewModel = new EventsLines();

    oEventViewModel = results.ToList().First();

    return PartialView(oEventViewModel);
}


    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetSubEventsDetails(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
        FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
        var toFind = new SubEventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053, Zkf_EVL = id };
        var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

        bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            return View();
        }

        IList<SubEventsLines> oEventViewModel = new List<SubEventsLines>();
        oEventViewModel = results.ToList();

        return PartialView(oEventViewModel);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model jak.formulaire.Models.EventViewModel

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-5" style="margin-top:2%">
        <h4>Registration History</h4>
        </div>
        @* Table of Events member *@
        <div>
            <table id="example" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%; margin-top:2%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Event Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model._EventsLines)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#myModal" class="myModal" data-foo="@item.Event_Name" id="@item.Zkp" onclick="GetEventsDetails(this.id)">@item.Event_Name</a></td>
                        <td>@item.Event_DateStart</td>
                        <td>@item.Event_DateEnd</td>
                        <td>@item.Event_Status</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    @* Modal Details *@
    <div class="modal" role="dialog" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Details of the event :</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="myModalContent">
                        <div class="container" style="width:auto; margin-top:1%">
                            <div class="row col-12">

                                    <div class="form-horizontal col-6" style="margin-left:-5%">

                                    </div>
                                    <table id="SubEventsDatatables" class="display col-12">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Fee</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model._EventsLines)
                                            {
                                            <div>
                                                { Html.RenderPartial("GetEventsDetails", item); }
                                            </div>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-12">

                                <div class="card border-primary" style="margin-top:5%; margin-left:-4%; width:113%">
                                    <div class="card-header"><h6>Sub-Events</h6></div>
                                    <div class="card-body">

                                        { Html.RenderPartial("GetSubEventsDetails", userId); }

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @*<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @section Scripts{

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function GetEventsDetails(id) {

                 //$('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text("Details ");

                 $.get("@Url.Action("GetEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
                     function (data) {
                         $('.modal-body').html(data);

                    })

                 $.get("@Url.Action("GetSubEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
                     function (data) {
                         $('.modal-body').html(data);

                    })

                 $('#myModal').show();
            }
        </script>
    }
                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function () {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function (event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

                function GetEventsDetails(id) {

                     //$('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text("Details ");

                     $.get("@Url.Action("GetEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
                         function (data) {
                             $('.modal-body').html(data);

                        })

                     $.get("@Url.Action("GetSubEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
                         function (data) {
                             $('.modal-body').html(data);

                        })

                     $('#myModal').show();
                }
            </script>
        }
```

**Partial view for the _EventLines**

```
@model jak.formulaire.Models.EventsLines

<div class="row col-12">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-6" style="margin-left:-5%">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Zkp, new { data_val = "false" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Zkf_CTC, new { data_val = "false" })
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">Start Date</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_DateStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Date Start", @id = "Event_StartDate" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">End Date</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_DateEnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Date End", @id = "Event_EndDate" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">City</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "City", @id = "Event_City" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">Country</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Country", @id = "Event_Country" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-horizontal col-6">
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">Type</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Type", @id = "Event_Type" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">Status</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Status", @id = "Event_Status" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
            <label class="control-label col-md-5" style="font-size:13px">Total Due</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event_TotalDue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7", @style = "font-size:13px, height:10px", @readonly = "", @placeholder = "Total Due", @id = "Event_TotalDue" } })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial view of the table with the _SubEventLines**

@model List

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

```
    <tr>
        <td>@item.SubEvent_Name</td>
        <td>@item.SubEvent_Date</td>
        <td>@item.SubEvent_Status</td>
        <td>@item.SubEvent_Fee</td>
    </tr>
```

}

**When it is in loading**

[image]

**Sometimes i see only the event:**

[image]

**And sometimes i only see the SubEvent.. just when i refresh the page and open the modal again...**

[image]

Comment: Model._SubEventsLines is a List of _SubEventsLine. So your model in Partial View should be @model jak.formulaire.Models.SubEventsLine and the same in the parameter of GetSubEventsDetails action method

Comment: Should i transform 'results' in a List<SubEventsLines>?

Comment: Already there is a for loop and you are calling the partial view for each subevent. So, you may change the above code to call the partial view and bring that loop to your partial view rather only a tr

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried to keep the foreach in my partialview of subevents but i does not work. Can i do something like "@foreach (var item in Model.SubEvent_Name)" since i know SubEvent_Name is never null?

Comment: For EventLines your action method is having this code EventsLines oEventViewModel = new EventsLines();

    oEventViewModel = results.ToList().First();.
Same way for SubEventLines it must be like this
SubEventsLines oSubEventViewModel = new SubEventsLines();

    oSubEventViewModel = results.ToList();

Comment: Where are you assigning the value to userId in modal view?

Comment: I dont, but i dont think i need it since my return partial subevent return the good value already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the subeventsdetails to below in Modal View:

```
     <div class="card-header"><h6>Sub-Events</h6></div>
          <div class="card-body">

              { Html.RenderPartial("GetSubEventsDetails", userId); }

           </div>
      </div>
```

and below in partial view

```
    @model List<jak.formulaire.Models.SubEventsLines>

    <table id="SubEventstables" class="display col-12">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Fee</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
             <div>
              <tr>
                 <td>@item.SubEvent_Name</td>
                 <td>@item.SubEvent_Date</td>
                 <td>@item.SubEvent_Status</td>
                 <td>@item.SubEvent_Fee</td>
              </tr>
            </div>
          }
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Change below in GetSubEventDetails action method

```
  IList<SubEventsLines> oEventViewModel = new List<SubEventsLines>();

  oEventViewModel = results.ToList();

  return PartialView(oEventViewModel);
```

Comment: It is not working because Model (from => var item in Model) "cannot work of variables of type 'SubEventsLines' because 'SubEventsLines' do not contains a public instance for 'GetEnumerator'".

Comment: SubEventLines should be same like EventLines class. So, both should be iterated through for loop. Check the implementation of both the classes.

Comment: Yep i know but this is exactly what doesnt work :/ i just did:          SubEventsLines oEventViewModel = new SubEventsLines();
            oEventViewModel = results.ToList();
but results.ToList() is highlighted in red and say "Cant convert System.Collections.Generic.List<jak.formulaire.Models.SubEventsLines> in jak.formulaire.Models.SubEventsLines".
It works for EventsLines because i only have one event so i could add .First() (so its not a list).

Comment: I think i should convert oEventViewModel to a list, nope?

Comment: No issue. I modified the above code. Just see if it works :)

Comment: Well i don't receive an error 500 anymore but it still not display the table with subevent in the modal :(

Comment: do you have values populated in return oEventViewModel to view?

Comment: Yep i receive the oEventViewModel, i add a screen in my first post.

Comment: Have you added  @model IList<jak.formulaire.Models.SubEventsLines> in partial view?

Comment: I've edited my post with the actual code + a picture who let you see the content of oEventViewModel (from GetSubEventDetails).

Comment: I just changed the @model of my partial view to an IList (i had List) but the result is still the same.

Comment: No issue, just modified the partial view. change above in partial view. If you still see the output. Just check the page source if any output is there in page source. Thanks!

Comment: I only see the SubEvent now :p

Comment: But i'm pretty sure that something is wrong in the body of my modal.. like  the partialview for the Event is in the tbody.. but it shouldnt! On the top-part of the modal i'm supposed to display the modal and on the bottom-part of the modal i must display the table with the sub-events..

Comment: Just check the page source if any output is there in page source. Thanks!

Comment: Yep i have 2 outputs, one with the event and one with the subevent

Comment: I just noticed a really strange behavior, i show you some images on my first post! Sometimes it display the event, sometimes it display the subevent (without changing the code...)

Comment: I think i understood whats wrong in my code! When i debug with Chrome i see my 2 outputs but one is hiding another for an unknow reason! I think what i need to do is return an object of EventViewModel (who contain a list of event and a list of subevents) and show both of those 2 lists in a unique partial view. Gonna try it tommorow.

Comment: @Korpin you may like to accept the above answer for your question. Thanks

Comment: Here we go, thanks agian for your help! It works now! What i had to do is put the Event and SubEvents in the same partial view.. But without your help i couldnt have done it!